# Linux - Render Special Shell Characters Literally

Tags: linux, shell

I'm attempting to connect to a local Windows share via samba with my credentials. the password I am using to connect contains a exclamation point. When I run this command, the shell inputs the last command I ran into the middle of the string where the ! was. How do I tell the shell to parse the string literally? I've tried enclosing the password in quotes and escaping with a "\" but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes.

If that still fails, use `set +H` to turn off <kbd>!</kbd> history expansion (and `set -H` to re-enable it).